# SimpleInjector: batch registration of classes with multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

Let's say I have the following classes that implement the following interfaces:

```
class MyClassA : IInterface<MyClassA>, IInterface
class MyClassB : IInterface<MyClassB>, IInterface
```

I have two other classes like the following:

```
class ImportA {
    public ImportA(IEnumerable<IInterface>) {}
}

class ImportB {
    public ImportB(IInterface<MyClassA>) {}
}
```

- I want ImportA to be injected with every class that implements `IInterface` in my assembly.
- I want ImportB to be injected with just an instance of `IInterface<MyClassA>`.
- I want the instance of concrete class MyClassA from both methods to be the same (LifeTime: Singleton).

I can't figure out how to get this to work with Simple Injector. I've tried `RegisterCollection` and https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto.html#register-multiple-interfaces-with-the-same-implementation

The closest I have come is getting an error saying one class imported as Singleton the other as Transient.

I've tried changing all the LifeStyles to Singleton and setting the config to Singleton by default, to no avail.

**UPDATE 1:**
I am looking for an automated approach. I have a lot of classes to register and don't want to have to do it by hand. Here is a different sample. The below registration examples didn't work. The automated one failed with:

```
An exception of type 'SimpleInjector.ActivationException' occurred in  
SimpleInjector.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The constructor of type MyClassB contains the 
parameter with name 'myClassA' and type IInterface<MyClassA> that is not 
registered. Please ensure IInterface<MyClassA> is registered, or change the 
constructor of MyClassB. There is, however, a registration for 
IEnumerable<IInterface<MyClassA>>; Did you mean to depend on 
IEnumerable<IInterface<MyClassA>>?
```

Here is my current code:

```
public interface IInterface {
  string Value { get; set; }
}

public interface IInterface<T> : IInterface { }

public class MyClassA : IInterface<MyClassA> {
  public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class MyClassB : IInterface<MyClassB> {
  private IInterface<MyClassA> myClassA;

  public MyClassB(IInterface<MyClassA> myClassA) {
    this.myClassA = myClassA;
  }

  public string Value {
    get { return this.myClassA.Value; }
    set { this.myClassA.Value = value; }
  }
}

public class ImportA {
  public ImportA(IEnumerable<IInterface> imports) {
    // fails on this line
    var a = imports.SingleOrDefault(i => i is IInterface<MyClassA>);
    a.Value = "test";

    var b = imports.SingleOrDefault(i => i is IInterface<MyClassB>);

    // should output the value of "test";
    Console.WriteLine(b.Value);
    Console.ReadKey();
  }
}

...
static void Main() {
  var container = new Container();

  var types = container.GetTypesToRegister(
    typeof(IInterface<>), new[] { typeof(IInterface<>).Assembly });

  var registrations = (
    from type in types
    select Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration(type, type, container))
    .ToArray();

  container.RegisterCollection<IInterface>(registrations);
  container.RegisterCollection(typeof(IInterface<>), registrations);

  var a = container.GetInstance(typeof(ImportA));
}
```

**ImportA** is the entry point and should be Transient.
Everything else should be singleton so that when MyClassA is modified in ImportA the value is picked up in MyClassB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to do this is by creating `Registration` instances manually and use them to register two separate collections. Example:

```
var a = Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration<MyClassA>(container);
var b = Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration<MyClassB>(container);

container.RegisterCollection<IInterface>(new[] { a, b });

container.AddRegistration(typeof(IInterface<MyClassA>), a);
container.AddRegistration(typeof(IInterface<MyClassB>), b);
```

This will ensure that the same single instance is used in both collections. If a class implements multiple generic versions of `IInterface<T>`, that same single instance will even be reused over the different collections for `IInterface<T>`.

If you want a more automated approach, you can do this:

```
var types = container.GetTypesToRegister(typeof(IInterface<>), assemblies);

// NOTE: The ToArray() call is crucial to prevent torn lifestyles.
var registrations = (
    from type in types
    select Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration(type, type, container))
    .ToArray();

container.RegisterCollection<IInterface>(registrations);

foreach (var registration in registrations) {
    container.AddRegistration(
        typeof(IInterface<>).MakeGenericType(registration.ImplementationType),
        registration);
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. I've updated my question with further information.

Comment: @RabidPenguin: I'm sorry. I missed the fact that the generic interfaces should not be registered as collection. I updated my question.

Comment: _registration.ServiceType_ doesn't exist. Do you mean _registration.ImplementationType_? That seems to work. So then when I do a container.GetInstance(typeof(ImportA)), would my Lifestyles be ImportA (Transient) > IEnumerable(IInterface) (Singleton) > IInterface<MyClassA> (Singleton)? I don't need to register ImportA, right?

Comment: @RabidPenguin yes, sorry. I had to write my answers from my mobile phone, so wasn't able to dact check it. `ImplementationType` is what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've marked your answer as correct. I'm new to Simple Injector, I've mostly just used MEF. Are there any "gotchas" I should be aware of? Do I need to dispose of any of my objects manually or does the container take care of that?

Comment: @RabidPemguin: The best advice I can give you is: Verify your container: https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto.html#verify-configuration. This is the killer feature that other IoC libraries lack and it can be a huge time saver in tracking down bugs. SI will dospose instances for you, except  transient instances. But Verify() will notify you when you made such registration.